# Client-side Javascript injection by assinging the output of window.location.href.substr to a variable

Tags: xss, javascript, dom

Sample code:

```
function winLoad() {
    var sessionId = '';
    if (window.location == window.top.location) {
        var semicolonIndex = window.location.href.indexOf(';');
        if (semicolonIndex != -1) {
            var questionMarkIndex = window.location.href.indexOf('?');
            if (questionMarkIndex != -1) {
                sessionId = window.location.href.substr(semicolonIndex, questionMarkIndex - semicolonIndex);
            } else {
                sessionId = window.location.href.substr(semicolonIndex);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Is it possible to inject arbitrary Javascript commands with the URL like this: `https://example.com;';alert(document.domain);'`? The input does not get reflected on the site and I've been trying to figure out how to close the string and add arbitrary commands right after it using browser consoles:

1. not a malicious payload `https://example.com/foo;bar` -> `";bar"`  in FF and `';bar'` in Chrome
2. malicious payload `https://example.com/foo;';alert(document.domain);'` -> `";';alert(document.domain);'"`, input get surrounded by double quotes
3. malicious payload `https://example.com/foo;";alert(document.domain);"` -> `";%22;alert(document.domain);%22"`, double quotes get encoded

I've also been trying to look up if the `location.href` method encodes double quotes only in some parts of the URL (path `/foo/`, query `?foo=bar` and hash `#foo`) but so far it seems that they always get encoded.

Comment: This piece of code does nothing special. Some text is assigned to a variable. Why do you expect anything special from this code? If this code is used somewhere else, then provide the full code.

Comment: Well I thought I could bypass encodings to end up with something like this: `sessionId = ";foo";alert(1);""` which I thought would cause a popup. But guessing from your answer I assume this doesn't work and you need some sort of a sink function that takes the payload as input?

Comment: Why do you think that just assigning some text to variable like `a = "alert(1)"` should *execute* this text?

Comment: I don't, what I thought I could do was this: initially the variable is declared like this `a = ""` and then after my input it will look like this `a = "";alert(1);""`, where my input is `";alert(1);" `. Maybe I'm under the wrong impression that this would close the double quotes of `a`, insert the `alert(1)` function and then add another double quote for the hanging double quote. So I would be left with `a = "";` followed by `alert(1);` followed by `""`. So `alert(1)` would not be part of the string.